# How can I get a localized string in a Factorio mod Lua script?

Tags: lua

How can I get a localized string in a Factorio mod Lua script?

`item.localised_name` contains only the key. I can use print({"",item.localised_name}) to print the localized name to the UI. but I want it in a variable to write it into a file.

Answer (score 2):

There's a couple different ways you could go about this. I'd recommend just passing the localised string to [`write_file`](https://lua-api.factorio.com/latest/classes/LuaGameScript.html#write_file) as it accepts localised strings and will translate it according to each player's locale when writing to the file.

Note that write_data also accepts the append parameter, so you can write your file in pieces for each bit you want to translate.

Alternatively, you can call [`request_translation`](https://lua-api.factorio.com/latest/classes/LuaPlayer.html#request_translation) if you want to have the translated value of a specific player's locale and you need it in your lua.

Note though that this is asynchronous so you get the result back in an event.

Comment: Rick: you mean write_file . but thank you, that helps. in the meantime I have pimped VSCode so that it shows me the parameters